# Openshift 4.1 installation on pre-existing virtual machines

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

Any pointers on how to install Openshift 4.1 on pre existing VMs ?

Hi,

I have pre-existing virtual machines that I need to use to install Openshift 4.1 and create a cluster. All the VMs can talk to each other and their IP addressed wont change. Can someone please provide me a detailed installation process for this setup ? I saw the bare metal documentation but I am not sure if all the steps apply to my virtual machines and some steps are not clear, especially how do I get coreOS to install on my VMs ? Where do I run the load balancer ? Do I require 1 or 2 load balancers ? Where is the infra node if there are 3 masters needed ? Where does the router run ?

Also is the http server creation mandatory ? Is there a chance I can use any existing one ?

I also want to use Container Native storage in 4.1. IS it possible ? IF yes, how do I install/configure it ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer your question as inline.

> I have pre-existing virtual machines that I need to use to install Openshift 4.1 and create a cluster. All the VMs can talk to each other and their IP addressed wont change. Can someone please provide me a detailed installation process for this setup ?

Refer [OpenShift 4.1 Bare Metal Install Quickstart](https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-4-bare-metal-install-quickstart/) for more details.

> I saw the bare metal documentation but I am not sure if all the steps apply to my virtual machines and some steps are not clear, especially how do I get coreOS to install on my VMs ?

The VM should boot with RHCOS iso image which can download from `cloud.redhat.com`.

> Where do I run the load balancer ? Do I require 1 or 2 load balancers ?

If your object is testing, then you can create the LB using HAProxy, refer Load Balancer section [OpenShift 4.1 Bare Metal Install Quickstart - Load Balancer](https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-4-bare-metal-install-quickstart/).

> Where is the infra node if there are 3 masters needed ?

3 masters are required for automatic upgrade. Because the upgrade is conducted 
by rolling update ways.

> Where does the router run ?

It's run on a worker node by default. So you need one compute node as least.

> Also is the http server creation mandatory ? Is there a chance I can use any existing one ?

Why not ?, you can use existing web server to provide some contents which is required when OCP4 installation. You just add related configuration to existing web server.

> I also want to use Container Native storage in 4.1. IS it possible ? IF yes, how do I install/configure it ?

Sorry about this question, I have no idea...

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any thoughts on persistent storage ? The official documentation says it is a pre requisite but none of the blogs mention configuring a persistent storage before installation. Can we install openshift 4.1 without doing anything to configure Persistent storage ?

Comment: @user1722908 Yes, you can install without PV, if you should change emptyDir for registry storage during installation as needed `oc patch configs.imageregistry.operator.openshift.io cluster \ --type merge --patch '{"spec":{"storage":{"emptyDir":{}}}}'` which the configuration step is written the blog I provided above.